# which files under src/main/resources and files under WEB-INF?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I'm using Maven nowadays and i have to "mavenize" a dynamic web project (J2EE/Eclipse) , i got the `application.war` succefuly built but when i deploy it in Tomcat, i got so much errors and i begin to resolve it and i know exactly what's the problem : i didn't place the right files Under the right folder !

So my question is : which files i have to place Under `src/main/resources` and wich files i'll keep it Under `WEB-INF` ?

i'll post a picture with all my files Under `WEB-INF` and hope that will help to answer :

[Files Under `WEB-INF`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeIz3.png)

Comment: It might be very helpful to compare the contents of the old and new versions of application.war.  You are not done until all the filepaths are corrects.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Yeah you're right , they give me the project  withou the war file :s so i'm tryin' to figure out alone and i'll spend more time than expected ... and everyday i got some new exceptions ! :D i'm impressed how much execptions are generated ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The files that should end up in the classpath (i.e. under `WEB-INF/classes` in the generated war file) should be in `src/main/resources`.

The files that should end up under the root of the war file should be in `src/main/webapp`. So, if you want a file to end up in `WEB-INF/foo/bar` in the generated war file, the file should be under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/foo/bar`. If you want a file to end up in `images` in the generated war file, the file should be under `src/main/webapp/images`

Comment: Thnx @JB Nizet but wanna more details with the example of my project, if u need more informations i'm available

Comment: It's quite simple. Everything that was under src in your previous , non-mavenized Eclipse project, but was not a Java file, should go under src/main/resources. Everything that was into WebContent in your previous Eclipse project should go under src/main/webapp. If you're in doubt, look at the war file generated by your previous project. Based on where the file is in this war file, deduce the location it should have in the project.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep frontEnd files like html,jsp,js,css files under web-inf which are to be used by application through links. all the static content like properties file and other utility items can be kept in src/main/resources.

Comment: thnx for your reply @Chetan